# use variable in aspx page load from event raised in ascx, and build dynamic buttons on page

Tags: asp.net

I dynamically build cookie crumbs (link buttons) at the top of an aspx page. As the user clicks other buttons on this page, the crumbs get populated. Each crumb has a hyperlink so the user can click it to go back into the section referenced by the crumb. Each time the user clicks a button on the owner.aspx page that should update the crumbs, I set a public variable, and refer to the variable in the sub that populates the crumbs. I call this sub for each postback on the page load.

I also have a people.ascx control in owner.aspx and want to update / populate the cookie crumbs in owner.aspx as the user clicks buttons in people.ascx.

To do this, I am trying to raise events in owner.aspx from people.ascx.

1. In the onclick sub of a button in people.ascx, I raise an event with: RaiseEvent UpdateOwnerCookieCrumbs("2A") // note that I am passing a variable "2A" in this example.
2. At the top of people.ascx, I declare the event with : Public Event UpdateOwnerLandingPeopleCrumbs(PeopleCrumbID As String)
3. At the top of owner.aspx, I declare the variable that I am passing from people.ascx with : Public Property PeopleCrumbID As String
4. In the page load of owner.aspx I add a handler to call the event with : AddHandler ucPeople_e.UpdateOwnerLandingPeopleCrumbs, AddressOf Me.BuildCrumbs

The crux of the problem is with the passing of the variable from people to owner.

The BuildCrumbs sub in owner.aspx is where I dynamically build the cookie crumbs that all get added into a placeholder in owner.aspx :

I build a button with code like this :

```
mybtn2.ID = "btnOwnerPeopleEmployees_Crumb"
mybtn2.ToolTip = "Manage my business employees"
mybtn2.Text = "Employees"
AddHandler mybtn2.Click, AddressOf OwnerLandingPeopleRedir
CookieCrumbs.Controls.Add(mybtn2)
```

OwnerLandingPeopleRedir in the button build above is a sub. So if the cookie crumb button is clicked in owner.aspx, the OwnerLandingPeopleRedir sub should be called.

Problem?

When the request to build the cookie crumbs in owner.aspx is raised from people.ascx, page load for owner.aspx occurs. Page load calls the buildcrumbs sub (1st time) without knowing the value of the PeopleCrumbID variable passed from people.ascx. Then the event handler in owner.aspx is raised and the buildcrumbs sub is called again (2nd time) and this time the PeopleCrumbID variable is recognized. Stepping through code all looks good. However, when I click the cookie crumb button in owner.aspx after postback, the hyperlink for the button does not call the OwnerLandingPeopleRedir sub. So the hyperlink is lost the second time code runs through buildcrumbs.

I tried calling the BuildCrumbs Sub from the page init event and every other event possible to see if building the crumbs earlier in the page lifecycle would help but that didn't make a difference.

I also tried changing my code to go with setting a session variable for peoplecrumb rather than passing it with the raiseevent, but that didn’t work either. In this case, what I found is that the cookie crumbs would get built successfully if I clicked a button 2 times... the programming would remember the old session variable value on first pass, and apply it successfully to build the crumbs … grrrr.

Does anyone have any idea how to help me get over this hump? PLEASE! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're doing that is causing your problem.  To be sure I understand, though... you have built a custom control (an .ascx) that you are adding to your web form dynamically by adding it to a placeholder control.  However, when the user interacts with the custom control, the event is not getting raised to the parent.

I think that you've got a good start here, but I'd like to give a recommendation on a slightly different way to approach this.  It might also clean up your code a little and keep you from having to build the control twice in one page lifetime.

First, change your "BuildCrumbs" sub to the following (you'll probably need to change the "Dim mybtn2" line to match the details of your project):

```
Private Sub BuildCrumbs(IsNewControl As Boolean)
    Dim mybtn2 As People = LoadControl("~/controls/people.ascx")

    mybtn2.ID = "btnOwnerPeopleEmployees_Crumb"

    If IsNewControl Then
        mybtn2.ToolTip = "Manage my business employees"
        mybtn2.Text = "Employees"
    End If

    AddHandler mybtn2.Click, AddressOf OwnerLandingPeopleRedir
    CookieCrumbs.Controls.Add(mybtn2)
End Sub
```

Next, get rid of the code in your Page_Load that is calling BuildCrumbs and instead put it in your placeholder's init event:

```
Private Sub CookieCrumbs_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CookieCrumbs.Init
    BuildCrumbs(Not Page.IsPostBack)
End Sub
```

The way dynamic controls work is that the first time you add it to the form you need to create everything about it, such as setting its ID, ToolTip, and Text properties.  However, on a postback, you just need to create the control with the ID property set and add it into the same location on the page, and the page's ViewState handling will repopulate the control with its proper values.

I have a sample project that I can provide you if you need further clarification.